# Catch error on IBM Watson IoT NodeJS client

Tags: javascript, node.js, watson-iot

I'm using the `IBM Watson IoT` `NodeJS` client to connect and use `IBM Watson IoT`.

This works when my object with credentials etc. is correct:

```
var client = new ibm_watson_iot.IotfGateway(MY-JSON-OBJECT-WITH-CREDENTIALS);
```

But if credentials is wrong, then I get:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 1234xyz.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com 1234xyz.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com:8883
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 1
```

How do I correctly catch this error in a nice way?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `try/catch` block to handler error like that

```
try{
     var client = new ibm_watson_iot.IotfGateway(MY-JSON-OBJECT-WITH-CREDENTIALS);
}

catch(error) {
  console.log("Error in connection.. Probably configuration object")
}
```